# Combining regex of characters and Strings in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I have a set of special characters, for ex. like ?. ^,! etc and also special string like && and | |, using these special characters and strings I have to write a regex that will escape all these special characters and string.

Output must be something like this: **\^\!\?\&\&\|\|**. However, the regex must not disturb the lonely "&" and "|", i.e. it must not escape any single presence of & and |.

I have written regex for special characters and string separately. But not able to combine them and get the desired output.

```
String regex_for_char = "([\!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\*\?])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_for_char);
String escapedContent = pattern.matcher(some_text).replaceAll("\\\\$1");

String regex_for_strings = "([|]{2}|&&)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(regex_for_strings);
String escapedStringCon = ptrn.matcher(some_text).replaceAll("\\\\S1");
```

How can I write a combined regex to match and escape in a single operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with lookarounds:

```
"(?<=&)&|&(?=&)|(?<=\\|)[|]|[|](?=\\|)|[\\]\\[!(){}^*?]"
```

Replace it by:

```
"\\\\$0"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iV0pE4/2)

Lookarounds for `&` and `|` are there to make sure `&&` and `||` are not escaped.

Comment: doesnt seem to work, basically has some problem with character class closing

Comment: Also, it is doing opposite of what I want. I.e. it is escaping lonely & and |.

Comment: But you wrote in question **it must escape any single presence of `&` and `|`** Can you clarify what you want to do with `&&` and what with `single `&`?

Comment: Sorry, second time I missed a "not" word.

Comment: What I want is : I have a set of special characters like :, ? , !,^, &&, | | in a content of a file. I must escape them and print back to file. However I shoudnot escape any presence of single & or |. Also when I encounter a && or || , the escaped content must be something like \&\& and \|\|.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
([\!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\*\?]|&(?=&)|(?<=&)&|[|](?=[|])|(?<=[|])[|])
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3vQ0/5)

Comment: I had tried this, but it doesnt give the desired output that  I have mentioned above. This expression would escape only the first letter i.e. & or | of  && or |.